# why are many of the Material elements giving this error? - "Not a known element"

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've inherited this application and I'm upgrading to the various angular versions and I've gotten the dreaded material items "is not a known element"

```
ERROR in ADMIN/afterhours-config/afterhours-config.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-card' is not a known element:
```

I've looked at the various other questions and answers and I would love to say that they have fixed my issue, but here I am...

In my admin.module.ts:

```
import { AfterhoursConfigComponent } from './afterhours-config/afterhours-config.component';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgModule,
    MaterialModule...]

  declarations: [
      AfterhoursConfigComponent,...]
```

Not sure what else I'm missing. I did see one comment about LazyLoading...  I honestly don't know if the application is doing that or not.  I'm not sure where to go from here!  There are tons of these errors everywhere in the application (**BUT NOT with EVERY MATERIAL element?**)...

**material.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { CdkAccordionModule } from '@angular/cdk/accordion';
import { ClipboardModule } from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    NgModule,
    A11yModule,
    CdkAccordionModule,
    ClipboardModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Comment: I'm not an Angular developer, so this may the way outta here, but would switching the two first `@import from ...` solve your issue?

Comment: Can you show us what the `material.module.ts` looks like? I suspect something is missing there.

Comment: @kellermat - added.  As you can see, the matcard module is included.  Please let me know if you see something I should add.

Comment: Can you remove `NgModule` from the exports resp. from the imports of `material.module.ts` and `admin.module.ts`. Not even is it unnecessary, but it might stop the application from working (at least in my local tests this was the case).

Comment: the `MaterialModule` should be added in the module "you has declared the component". e.g. if you declare a component in `A.module.ts`, is in this module -not in main.module.ts-. Think in a module as "some" you can import without know about the main.module. Yes, is the component is declared in main.module. Well, It's looks like you doit so... has you install material `ng add @angular/material`? Another question: sometimes it's neccesary re-init the ng-server when you create a module or added some to a module, it's your case?

Comment: In admin.module.ts I am including materialmodule - This was an upgrade project so I have upgraded to angular/material 13

Comment: @kellermat - I believe your comment was the closest to the answer for me.  I'm working on a new issue, but I do want to come back to this question and write up an answer for it.    My project had multiple module.ts files and the NgModule needed to be removed in the non "child" module.ts files (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which versions you updated they changed the way some modules are imported I would go to the docs for that specific module or check out https://update.angular.io/ and see the changes between versions.